# How to invoke a chain/other commands using one command in discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot. I want something like i invoke a command "-f" in an channel, i want this to invoke other commands or function in other channels and thread automatically like  "-f a" in b,"-f +emote2" in c and so on,

here is a snip of code

```py
@bot.command()
    async def f(ctx, *args):
      result = False
    
      if not args:
          await ctx.channel.purge(limit=900)
          await asyncio.sleep(0.21)
          channel_A = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="pins")
          if channel_A:
              await channel_A.send("-f +")
              await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('-f +')) 
          else:
             await ctx.send("Channel A not found.")
     //there more code but it long and irelevant i think
```

i can see the mesage being send but it is not invoking the other command.
it shows an error as well

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\M Muzammil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Personal\Auto upload\BOT.py", line 60, in f
        await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('-f +'))
      File "c:\Users\M Muzammil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\context.py", line 336, in invoke
        return await command(self, *args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```